# A generic process to convert a file to display format

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos

Is there a generic process to convert a file on z/OS to display format?
I have a couple hundred files on z/OS I need to convert to Display format before they are NDM to the midrange/Linux.  These files contain compressed fields.  I'm doing this because I want the files to land on the midrange as ASCII and not as EBCDIC/binary.  I'm also trying to avoid writing a COBOL conversion routine for each file.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So, you are looking for a way to take a file that has packed decimal, EBCDIC, and other binary data and convert it with a utility ?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM has a utility on the mainframe that can probably do what your asking.  The utility is called IEBPTCH (IEB Print Punch).  The documentation is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.idau100/iebptpc.htm)

Its not automatic but could be easier than writing code.  From the doc

> You can use IEBPTPCH to print or punch all, or selected portions, of a
> sequential or partitioned data set or PDSE. Data can also be "printed"
> or "punched" to disk or tape.
>
> IEBPTPCH can be used to print or punch:
>
> - A sequential or partitioned data set or PDSE, in its entirety
> - Selected members from a partitioned data set or PDSE
> - Selected records from a sequential or partitioned data set or PDSE
> - The directory of a partitioned data set or PDSE
> - An edited version of a sequential or partitioned data set or PDSE
> - A data set containing double-byte character set data
> - You can specify the format for the records that you are printing or punching, or you can use IEBPTPCH's default formats.
>
> - The default formats are:
> - Each logical output record begins on a new printed line or punched card.
> - Each printed line consists of groups of eight characters separated by two blanks.
> - Up to 96 data characters can be included on a printed line.
> - Each punched card contains up to 80 contiguous bytes of information.
> - Characters that cannot be printed appear as blanks.
> - When the input is blocked, each logical output record is delimited by "*" and each block is delimited by "**".
>   Sixty lines per page will be printed.

See the `RECORD` statement [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.idau100/u1377.htm)

Comment: Thank yo so much.  I take a look at the utility

Answer (score 2):

Mainframe SORT utilities typically excel at data conversions.  They also typically use less CPU and run in less clock time than other utilities, which may be less of a concern for a one-time process.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to avoid writing new COBOL programs. But take a look at the RENDER keyword.
I will convert a COBOL 01 ... grouping into a valid XML structure in a single line of code. Using SORT or IEBPTCH is just programming in a weird language.